# document.createElement not working on IE 8 and below

Tags: javascript, html

I have this for that lets users upload pictures. I wanted to limit the number of pictures to 4. At first it shows only one input field, then if a user wants to add more they can click on Button-Add-icon.png and another input field appears. When they reach four inputs and they decide to remove one they click on Button-Delete-icon.png.

This whole thing works fine on Firefox, Chrome, Seamonkey and IE9. But it doesn't work on IE8, IE7 and before.
Could someone give a hint on how to get it fixed?

Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org 
 /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Document sans titre</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   var totalItems = 0;
   function addItems()
 {
   if(totalItems < 3) 
  {
  var table1 = document.getElementById('tab1');
  var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
  var newcol = document.createElement("td");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type="file";
  input.name="image[]";
  newcol.appendChild(input);
  newrow.appendChild(newcol);
  table1.appendChild(newrow);
  totalItems++;
  } else {
    //Display your message here.. 
         }
 }


  function remItems()
{
var table1 = document.getElementById('tab1');
var lastRow = table1.rows.length;
if(lastRow>=2) 
 {
 table1.deleteRow(lastRow-1);
 totalItems--; 
 }
}

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>

 <table align="center" border="0" id="tab1" >
  <tr>
   <td width="218" align="center"><input type="file" name="image[]" /></td>
      <td width="54" align="center"><img src="images/Button-Add-icon.png"  
      style="cursor:pointer" onclick="addItems()" />
      </td>
   <td><img src="images/Button-Delete-icon.png"  style="cursor:pointer" 
    onclick="remItems()" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

  <table align="center" border="0" id="tab2">
  </table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think that instead of doing those appends, you should set the innerHTML of each to fix the issue, let me fiddle it to find out.

Comment: why is this taged jquery when you are not using jquery at all?

Comment: Do the variables `newrow`, `newcol`, and `input` become `null` or `undefined` after the `createElement` call? Do you get an error message? How do you know `createElement` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the row as a child to the wrong element.

An HTML table always has a `tbody` element as a child element, all `tr` elements go inside this. If you write a piece of HTML including a table with no `tbody` element it will be created automatically, but when altering the table later on you have to take the `tbody` element into account.

An easy fix is to write the `tbody` element explicitly, give it an id, and insert new rows in the `tbody` element instead of in the `table` element.

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tb1">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```